# onActivityResult in ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I am invoking gallery from Child Activity and getting the path of selected image in parent ActivityGroup's onActivityResult method but i want to display selected image in an ImageView of Child Activity. How to do this?

Comment: pass the image path thru intent to that child activity.. in child activity get the image from path and set to imageview,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get `data` from `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

So you can get it by :

```
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
imageView.setImageURI(targetUri);
```

Comment: Yeah but its Parent's onActivityResult method called and i have set it to child's Imageview